# How to tell pylint to look in other files for variables?

Tags: python, vim, pylint, syntastic

I'm using the pylint python linter via Syntastic in Vim. It's great, except that I'm getting a lot of `undefine-variable` messages when calling functions that are defined in other modules that are then imported. Is it possible to configure Syntastic so that pylint looks in all files reachable from my current directory?

Comment: Is your working directory of vim correctly at the root of your project and are other files readable from there through proper packages with `__init__.py` files?

Comment: Yes, with empty __init__.py files

Comment: And this also happens if you run pylint manually on the file?

Comment: Yes, it does indeed

Comment: Can you make `pylint` not complain about undefined variables when running it from the command line?

Comment: I just tested this with a dummy example without any problems. In order to solve this we need a minimal working example and the exact pylint version.